# populate drop down list from database using mysqli prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, distinct, html-select

As the title says i want to generated data from database and show it in dropdown. I made a code and it doesn't show any error but the thing is it echos the code in dropdown. It works when i just echo it. And one more thing is it doesn't show DISTINCT results.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>FILTER</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'conn.php';?>

<?php
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT author, book_name, language FROM bk_tst_fltr ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($author,$book_name,$language);
    $stmt->store_result();
    echo "<select name='book'>";
    while($row=$stmt->fetch()){?>
        <p><?php echo  '<option value="$row["author"]">"$row["author"]"</option>'; ?></p>
    <?php }
    echo "</select>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Is shows `$row["author"]` in the dropdown.

Can anyone solve this problem???

Thank You.

My DATABASE

```
id  author  book_name language price
1   Kishore One       english  500
2   Kumar   two       english  600
3   Kishore three     german   700
```

Comment: if you want only author populated - why do you select book_name and language too?

Comment: i wanted to get them all in separate drop down

Comment: You can't have them all from single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use double quotes for variable expanding, or exit the string and concat normally.

Also, change to `while($stmt->fetch()){?>`

```
echo '<option value="'.$author.'">"'.$author.'"</option>';
```

Try also using this query instead:

```
"SELECT author, book_name, language FROM bk_tst_fltr GROUP BY author"
```

Comment: Try the edit, I removed, `$row=`, and since you bind, you can use the variables directly.

Comment: it shows the result surrounded by "" like this "author name" and it doesnt show distinct result

Comment: i want distinct result. no repeated author name

Comment: I know, but I would like to see what you database currently looks like.

Comment: i have added database structure in the question

Comment: I would like to see some example rows from that table.

Answer (score 1):

The very statement of question is wrong.

#### Prepared statements has absolutely nothing to do with dropdown lists.

And never have to be.

What you have to populate is an **array.** Which later have to be used in a **template.**

So, divide your question into two.

1. How to select some data into array.
2. How to output an array in a template.

Comment: I got this from a tutorial using mysql. They used query to do this and got it. How am i supposed to do that without prepared statements.

Comment: Well your tutorial is wrong. How you are supposed to do that, is explained in my post: **You have to populate an array first.** Once you done with it, you can go for the next.

Comment: can you add a link to your post